# How to create a microphone preamplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, microphone, class-d

I am quite new to audio electronics, but also to electronics in general.
I have tried to do quite a lot of research, but still cannot find enough information to make a proper amplifier for a mono microphone input.

I have managed to create an amplifier using a simple op-amp with a feedback loop, which was great and worked, but it had really crazy noise when touching the cables and also noise in general when I spoke into the mic.

I have talked with a friend at work who suggested me to use a class D amplifier circuit, however this time, I did not manage to connect it properly.

What I am looking for is some general information on how to configure some basic setup for amplifying the mic signal to be picked up by some basic speakers.

If anyone is willing to help set me on proper path, here is the stuff I do not really understand:

1. How much power does a class D amp need to amplify the mic signal to line level, is 2 x 3 W enough? The mic has an output impedance of 600 Ω and a sensitivity of ~-70 dB.
2. Is connecting the mic to the class D amp and then to the speakers enough for it to work? Or do I need something more, I am not even sure if the signal that goes to the class D amp doesn't have to be amplified by a normal op-amp first.
3. Is it typical that the class D amplifier circuit needs an external frequency generator, like a NE555? I have one pin that I don't knowwas what to connect to labeled "SW". The amplifier has no documentation (typical in my country) but I assume it is for the frequency generator.
4. (This one might sound stupid, but I am trying to avoid mistakes.) The amplifier output is L-, L+, R-, R+, since I want the output to go to a stereo jack, do I just connect the + and - of each channel together to replicate the alternating current output?

P.S.: With the original setup, I am not sure if maybe I have gone through the roof with the amplification and that's why it picked up so much noise, but since loudness of sounds are being perceived logarithmically, maybe if I halved the gain it would still sound similar but without the noise.

Comment: In music recording and sound reinforcement  term "mic preamplifier" is considered to be a device which lifts the millivolt grade mic output to easy to handle level, which is generally hundreds of millivolts. That is called "line level". High quality mic preamp is far from trivial if you want to catch silent speech from a distance longer than a few inches, say from 1 meter and to do it without inserting audible hiss to the signal. I guess you actually want an amplifier which contains a mic preamp + power amp which can feed a loudspeaker. Specify the wanted sound dB level and the distance for it

Comment: Research the [differences between mic-level, line-level, and speaker-level](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=understanding+mic+level+line+level+speaker+level&t=opera&ia=web).

Comment: What sort of microphone is it? Is it a headset microphone (electret) or a dynamic microphone or a condenser microphone?

Comment: Or carbon mic? Ribbon? MEMS? If electret, does it have internal JFET amplifier?

Comment: continued) If someone really has suggested you to get a class D mic preamplifier and he really said class D preamplifier you should immediately rise the believing treshold higher. The "instructor" very likely has based his  unbreakable confidence on watertight ignorance. BTW NE555 is not the most important part of class D amplifiers.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for all the answers. Here are some more specification based on your replies.
The mic is dynamic one, it says "Sensitivity rating of -75dB" I am not sure how to interpret that, however I lived under impression that it is an info on how low volume it can pickup.
I would like to make diy karaoke box into which I would input 2 microphones and output from TV to feed into a soundbar system. I believe I have taken wrong direction here, so if anyone has a good suggestion on how to approach this I'd be glad. Maybe how does such machine usually work nowadays, does it use just op amp?

Answer (score 1):

1. Wattage has nothing to do with that. Gain does. Mic sensitivity is also unlikely to be given as simple dB value, because it does not say dB in reference to what and under which conditions (they may be obvious and thus not given, or just incomplete info).
2. Depends on what kind of input stage the amplifer has and how much gain it has. It might not be suitable for directly conneting mics. At least not without a proper interface circuit to the mic. But the mic type is unknown too.
3. No, not typical. Besides it is hard to think of any reason why a modern amplifer chip would need a 50-year old NE555 as a companion chip to work. The datasheet of the chip would tell what each pin is for.
4. No, it would short the D class output. Sounds like whatever chip you have, it has a differential output and likely is meant to drive a pair of speakers directly.

If you have something with no manual available, don't buy or use it.